# I can't use a checkbox due to formatting error in my code

Tags: c#

I'm coding a program in C# and it's goal is to modify in game values. You probably know minecraft and i'm talking about reach. I need help since i don't know how to fix this and theres no tutorials or help of any kind for this.

The translation (i think) of the error it gives:

```
This exception was initially thrown in this call stack:
    [External code]
    Rain_Client.Form1.bunifuCheckbox1_OnChange (object, System.EventArgs) in Form1.cs
    [External code]
    Rain_Client.Program.Main () in Program.cs
```

the specific line that fails:

```
string text = BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToDouble("3.1"))).Replace("-", " ");
```

And the whole project:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Rain_Client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        static IntPtr[] lista;

        DotNetScanMemory_SmoLL dot = new DotNetScanMemory_SmoLL();
        private void bunifuCheckbox1_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bunifuCheckbox1.Checked)
            {
                bunifuCheckbox2.Checked = false;

                string text = BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToDouble("3.1"))).Replace("-", " ");
                lista = dot.ScanArray(dot.GetPID("javaw"), "00 00 00 00 00 00 08 40 00 00 00 00 00");
                for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count<IntPtr>(); i++)
                {
                    dot.WriteArray(lista[i], text);
                }
            }
        }

        private void bunifuCheckbox2_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bunifuCheckbox2.Checked)
            {
                string text = BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToDouble("3.2"))).Replace("-", " ");
                lista = dot.ScanArray(dot.GetPID("javaw"), "00 00 00 00 00 00 08 40 00 00 00 00 00");
                for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count<IntPtr>(); i++)
                {
                    dot.WriteArray(lista[i], text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the intended behavior of the failing line? Perhaps if the question is a bit more refined it'd be easier to answer.
Running just the line you specified, returns "CD CC CC CC CC CC 08 40" for me.
Or maybe even if you include the error you get?

Comment: @Joe_DM 
The intended behavior of the line is to modify the reach value wich is set to 3 in game to 3,2 or 3,1 when the checkbox is checked i'll make an edit to include the error but it's in french so i'll have to translate it the best i can. EDIT: Done, the error is in the post now

Comment: The line you mention is failing seems to work okay. Are you sure that's where the error is? As a test, you could try temporarily replacing the line with `var text = "CD CC CC CC CC CC 08 40";` which should set text to the same value but remove all the logic to re-calculate it every time. I suspect it will still fail and that the error is somewhere else.

Comment: @Joe_DM
I will try what you said but did you try to compile the whole project?

Comment: The snipped included in your question isn't enough to try to compile and run a sample locally. It looks like a windows forms application which would have more files for the form initialization and other stuff. It also doesn't indicate which references you're using. e.g. is DotNetScanMemory_SmoLL from a NuGet package or similar?
I might not have any java processes running which I could test against either.

Comment: @Joe_DM
[References](https://imgur.com/a/PWpLNFR)

Comment: I'm in the process of building a new windows form application to try to replicate your sample. One thing I notice is that a checkbox does not have an `OnChange` event. Did you create this code using the UI to automatically scaffold everything?
e.g. Go into the designer, click on the checkbox, then go to properties and select the events tab (looks like a lightning bolt) and in there double click on the `CheckedChanged` event.

Comment: @Joe_DM
I was using bunifuCheckbox and it was there by default

Comment: Roger. Let me go and try to find that control and test it with that. I was using default controls.

Comment: I can't try a sample because it's a paid product but looking at the doco on https://docs2.bunifuframework.com/docs/ui/controls/bunifu-checkbox it seems that the event is also `CheckedChanged`.
It's hard to know if this has changed over different versions but might be worth a shot. You will also need to subscribe to the event. e.g. There should be code in the {formName}.Designer.cs file that says something like `this.bunifuCheckbox1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.bunifuCheckbox1_CheckedChanged);`

Comment: Also, Maybe it's worth a test if this works with the default checkbox control, before moving to a more advanced one. Just to rule out any issues there.

Comment: @Joe_DM
i tested with normal checkboxes and same error and theres not that line of code you specified should be in Form1.Designer.cs but when i try to include it theres just a bunch of errors

Comment: I put in an answer that goes into a bit more detail. Did you want to try that and see if we can narrow down the issue? It's possible the the event is called `OnChange` in your version so in that case the line you need to subscribe would be `this.bunifuCheckbox1.OnChange += new System.EventHandler(this.bunifuCheckbox1_OnChange);`
or if the event is called `CheckedChanged` but you haven't renamed your method, then it would be `this.bunifuCheckbox1.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.bunifuCheckbox1_OnChange);`.
At the moment we're kind of guessing blind though.

Comment: @Joe_Dm
Where do i put this line in Form1.Designer.cs file?
`this.bunifuCheckbox1.OnChange += new System.EventHandler(this.bunifuCheckbox1_OnChange);`

Comment: Well, Visual studio should do this all for you automatically, but anywhere inside of the `InitializeComponent()` function would be pretty standard. Technically, you could even put it directly in the Form load but it wouldn't be as neat and tidy.

Comment: @Joe_DM
Doesn't change anything, still have the error. ;(

Comment: `Convert.ToDouble("3.1")` will fail if the decimal separator of the current culture is not a dot, but a comma

Answer (score 0):

After some back and forwarding discussing the question via comments I have considered my answer and I think the primary issues here is trying to do too much too fast.

I would recommend that when troubleshooting these kind of issues, the problem should be narrowed down and simplified wherever possible to understand the root cause and focus on the right area.

For example, we have a lot going on here. We're trying to attach to a remote process, edit pointers, toggle checkboxes, render custom controls which haven't been tested or proved.

Among all of this we know that there is an issue with the checkbox, but theres a lot of noise that we simply don't know if it's relevant or not.

I would recommend starting with a fresh project and slowly introduce components until the issue is identified.

e.g.
Create a simple default checkbox that does something simple like:

```
    private void checkbox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I was checked!");
    }
```

If that works then you can either try the same with the custom Bunifu and build on top of that.

It's possible that one of the components were not scaffolded correctly in which case everything should build and work as intended in the new project. However if you do have another issue then it will be clear where the issues started and easier to ask a more focused question with a simple example that is easy to replicate and answer.

Comment: I did this, everything worked fine so iwas wondering if you had any idea of how i could recode that line and get the same result without that error? Is there another way to convert? when i switched the line with `var text = "CD CC CC CC CC CC 08 40";` my program just freezes

Comment: In this case since you're converting a static value 3.1, the result is always going to be the same. It would be more efficient to just use the pre-converted value although I don't think either case is what causes your program to freeze. Are you familiar with the debugger and how to step through the code as it executes? This could show you what it's trying to do when it freezes.

Comment: No i'm not familiar with the debugge runfortunately

Comment: I'm still not clear on what the issues is which makes it hard to help. If the program is running and freezing you should be able to attach a debugger (usually just press play and it's automatic) and set a break point where you want the code to pause so you can inspect it. Maybe do some research and learn how to debug. It's a pretty good skill that can help troubleshoot many issues.